# Has anyone made a modified TeX with infinity greater than 10,000?

Tags: tex-core, badness

We're all familiar with the effect of `\sloppy` deciding that if there has to be something bad in the paragraph, it might as well shove everything into one *really* bad line. Part of this is, no doubt, due to the fact that in badness calculations, TeX has set infinity to the relatively low value of 10,000. This made a lot of sense when badness was calculated with 16-bit numbers but if I recall correctly, it's been a long time since the backing data structure was a 16-bit number. Has anyone ever tried making a modified version of TeX with a larger value for infinity? Did it help?

Comment: not as far as I know. I'd be surprised if it made any difference the badness usually only matters as in 0 small medium infnity  it's not often that the exact number matters much.

Comment: You might look at etex, but I believe it only increases the number of registers, not the size of them.

Comment: From Patrick's talk about "boxes and glue" at TUG2022 (or DANTE2022) he has re-implemented some TeX internal things he needs for his daily work.  His reimplementation covers nodes, glue, h and v boxes, line breaking and therefore I assume that he also has implemented the badness calcuation.  See <a href="https://boxesandglue.dev/">Boxes&Glue</a> or the TUG2022 talk for more, and in his <a href="https://github.com/speedata/boxesandglue/blob/main/backend/node/linebreak.go">linebreak</a> code part I see the badness calculation in the function "calculateDemerits" ...simple to change and play with

Comment: @BerndRaichle Thanks, FYI you can do links in Markdown syntax: typing `[Boxes & Glue](https://boxesandglue.dev)` produces: [Boxes & Glue](https://boxesandglue.dev)

Answer (score 2):

An old question without an answer and I think a few things shall be
put into the correct context although I haven't increased the badness
value in a TeX implementation.

First: No, `\badness` is not a 16-bit integer. It is a full TeX integer
and thus can be as large as $2^{31}-1$. And TeX uses one value larger
than 10000: `\setbox0=\hbox to 1pt{?}\showthe\badness` gives 1000000, clearly not a 16-bit number.

Probably you know that during the line breaking a badness of 800 means
the used space is two times the amount of available space. This looks
bad. (I would rewrite my text if such a value occurs.) A badness of
2700 means it's three times, 6400 means four times, 12500 five times,
and 21600 six times. The TeXbook, page 29, shows the effect.

So when even values less than 1000 are intolerable during the line
breaking, why should one start to distinguish badness values of 12500
and 21600? Page breaking is similar but there are reasons why the
badness might be a little bit larger than during line breaking. There
is no `\tolerance` but only the parameter `\vbadness`.

TeX itself has the dimen parameter `\emergencystretch` that
artificially increases the badness limit during line breaking. Knuth
introduced it to avoid high values of `\tolerance`. See
https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb10-3/tb25knut.pdf, p.327. (As far as I know
`\sloppy` makes use of `\emergencystretch` too; thus it doesn't just set
`\tolerance` to a high value.)

Thus, as @DavidCarlisle already stated in a comment, it doesn't make much sense to increase the range.

Final remark; From you profile I see that you might not have worked
with TeX78 but you might know what the file errorlog.tex is. Entry 296
for TeX78 is

> R296. Force \\{badness} to be at most $10^{19}$. @108

So, clearly, `\badness` wasn't 16 bit at that time too. And maybe one
can say that Knuth experimented with a TeX that has a larger range
than 0--10000 for badness. But I haven't studied the code in
TEXSEM.SAIL and it might stand for a different concept.